# Why doesnt the early.stop.round argument in xgboost work?

Tags: r, xgboost

I try to use the `early.stop.round` argument in the `xgb.cv` function of the `xgboost` library, however, I got an error. After I leave the `early.stop.round` unspecified, the function runs without any problem. What did I do wrong?

Here is my example code:

```
library(xgboost)

train = matrix(as.numeric(1:100),20,5)
Y = rep(c(0,1),10)
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(train, label=Y)

#cross validation when early.stop.round =5, gives an error
CV = xgb.cv(data = dtrain, nround=200, nfold =2, metrics=list("auc"), 
            objective = "binary:logistic",early.stop.round = 5)


#cross validation when early.stop.round is not specified, works
CV = xgb.cv(data = dtrain, nround=200, nfold =2, metrics=list("auc"),
            objective = "binary:logistic")
```

I am using `xgboost_0.4-2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like something goes wrong when using the metrics parameter and early.stop simultaneously. Remove metrics and use early.stop with eval_metric="auc" instead.